# How to use filter in Java stream API with JSON array

Tags: java, arrays, json, filter, stream

I am trying to use the stream API's filter function with Vert.x's `JsonArray` and `JsonObject` libraries. My IDE (IntelliJ) doesn't complain about the code below, but when I run the code, I get an exception.

```
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;

public JsonArray getNewItems(int group, int section) {
  JsonArray itemInfo = new itemsManager().getItems();
  JsonArray newItems = (JsonArray) itemInfo.stream().filter(i -> {
    return ((JsonObject) i).getInteger("group").equals(group) &&
           ((JsonObject) i).getInteger("section").equals(section);
  }).collect(Collectors.toList());
  return newItems;
}
--------
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray
```

If I change the above code to

```
List<Object> newItems = rowFacings.stream()...
```

then my code runs fine, but this presents a new set of problems.

How can I filter a JSON array of JSON objects into a new JSON array?

**EDIT**

This might be library related, as I am using Vert.x's `io.vertx.core.json` package. I will test in a bit (`org.JSON`, `com.google.gson`, etc...) in the spirit of knowledge seeking and update this post with any results in a bit.

Comment: how is this a duplicate to the aforementioned post? @nullpointer

Comment: where are you initially declaring `newItems` and how?

Comment: @scigs That was an error in my code. Updated.